# enabling HTML table specific border?

Tags: html

How to enable specific border of HTML table, say,
only left verticle, 
only right verticle or  
only upper horizontal or 
only lower horizontal or any?

```
A-------------------B-----------------C
|                   |                 |   
|                   |                 | 
D-------------------E-----------------F 
|                   |                 | 
|                   |                 | 
G-------------------H-----------------I
```

I am looking to enable only the line `BEH` without any css, but only with `table`, `tr`,  `td` tags.

Comment: see my link http://jsfiddle.net/8M2wp/1033/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8M2wp/1033/

```
table {
    border-top: double;
    border-bottom: double;
    border-right: blank
}
thead, tbody, tfoot {
    border-top: solid;
    border-bottom: solid
}
```

[see here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Tables/examples.html) For more examples

Comment: ok wait i will give for that.Then you can simply add the table id before the table in css

Comment: This does not answer the question asked (it explicitly says “without any css”).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<table rules=cols>
```

The [`rules` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#adef-rules) controls borders between cells, and this setting sets then only between columns.

This answers the question asked, but it is generally much better to use CSS for the purpose. That way, you can also control the type, width, and color of the border. In HTML, you can only set the color, and even that only using a nonstandard attribute too, e.g. `<table rules=cols bordercolor=red frame=void>`.